# Include Some jars while making a project jar and exclude others?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I am using maven for my development purposes. I have a requirement that I want to include some of the third party jar in my project jar and exclude others specified in pom.xml file. Below is my `pom.xml` file.

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.ckdm</groupId>
<artifactId>Exporter</artifactId>
<version>atlas2.1</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Exporter</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <aspectj.version>1.6.10</aspectj.version>
    <org.springframework.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>        
</properties>

<build>
     <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            <executions>
                    <execution>
                            <id>make-assembly</id> 
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ckdm</groupId>
        <artifactId>CubeCreator</artifactId>
        <version>atlas2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.guavus</groupId>
        <artifactId>ConcurrentFlows</artifactId>
        <version>atlas2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ps</groupId>
        <artifactId>thriftGenerated</artifactId>
        <version>atlas2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>apache</groupId>
        <artifactId>libthrift</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.20.203.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>   
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>

</project>
```

I read somewhere that specifying scope as provided doesn't include the jar's in the project jar. Where am I getting wrong, it is not able to include any of the jars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per your above comments, I assume you have one jar which has your main class in it.

Add `MANIFEST.MF` file in you project. Its contents should be like below:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-path: YourMainJar.jar thirdparty1.jar thirdparty2.jar
Main-Class: com.test.mymainclass
```

`YourMainJar.jar` is the file in which you have your main class, third party jars needs to be on the same location where your `YourMainJar.jar` is placed.

When you double click your `YourMainJar.jar`, it will automatically run and also pick your third party jars from the same location.

Note: You need to include this `MANIFEST.MF` when you are packing your project as jar.

Comment: This one works. Just curious to know, Is there any way that I can do this through maven. Like, Specifying some thing in pom.xml such that it includes some of my third party referred jars with my project jar.? I did a search, it is possible to include all of the third party referred jar by creating an assembly jar of the project. However, didn't find anything on including only some of the referred jars.???. .

Comment: you might want to look at this answer....[LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421266/how-to-configure-manifest-only-once-in-pom-xml-in-a-desktop-application)

Answer (score 0):

From [maven docs](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) for `provide`,

> This is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime. For example, when building a web application for the Java Enterprise Edition, you would set the dependency on the Servlet API and related Java EE APIs to scope provided because the web container provides those classes. This scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath, and is not transitive.

By using the scope `provided`, it actually assumes that the container is going to provide the dependency at runtime. But not all of the dependencies you added are actually provided by the container.

Comment: Yeah, I used scope as provided for the libraries I do not want to use in project jar. and i haven't used scope-provided for the dependency that I want to include in my jar while making the project jar.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the scope tag.

If you still have problem, use my working xml.

```
  <!--               Build complete JAR with all dependencies         -->
        <!-- mvn clean install assembly:single -->
                <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>jar-with-dependencies</id>
                                <phase>install</phase>
                                <goals><goal>single</goal></goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <archive>
                                        <manifest>
                                            <mainClass>com.mawia.YourMainClass</mainClass>
                                        </manifest>
                                    </archive>
                                    <descriptorRefs>
                                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                                    </descriptorRefs>
                                    <finalName>consumer</finalName>
                                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by third party jar in 'project jar'? If you have any third party jars that you want to include then add them by adding there dependency from maven repo or locally.

If you dont want any jar file in your project classpath then remove its dependency.

For local you use :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>testjar</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/testjar.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: simply adding the dependency wont include those third party jars into my jar. so if I run my project jar somewhere else, it wont be able to find those libraries which were in the third party jar. Thx.

Comment: maven is for building the project not running the project. If you want the jars when you run your project then add them to your classpath of project. If you are packing your project in jar then add your jars in your manifest file.

Comment: I acept your point. I am just saying If you want to make a bundled jar including some ( and not all ,) of the referred libraries by your project, how should it be done?